# How to make a program that display something and after 10 seconds automatically redirect to another site?

Tags: google-search-console

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
    sleep(10);
    header("Location: " . "http://google.com");
?>
```

The problem with this is that header is already sent

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/provenda/public_html/silverslady.com/index.php:46) in /home2/provenda/public_html/silverslady.com/index.php on line 75
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use only HTML to do this by using the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://redirectedurl.com/">
```

`redirectedurl.com` is the new URL you want redirect to afeter 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 ways to do this:

```
<?php
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/">';
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
    header("refresh:10;url=http://example.com");
?>
```

I'd recommend the second option.

About the "headers already sent"-error. That is commonly know as "the whitespace problem". Here is an exceptionally good response concerning the subject: [stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/668236](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/668236)